# Cookie is lost(thrown to logged out state) when killing/closing PWA App

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, progressive-web-apps

I have built an web application using Nuxt.js. I have also added PWA features with the help of @nuxtjs/pwa library. Everything works great offline features, installing the app etc except one thing and that is when I install the PWA(or loggin in the browser it self) and log in and when I try to kill or close the PWA App it seems like it removes the cookie from cookie storage that I am using as Auth Token. When I again open the PWA App I am logged out/cookie is lost.

I tried couple of solutions. This is the **First one**

```
this.$cookies.set("MY_AUTH_KEY", token, {
  // sameSite: 'lax',
  path: "/",
  maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
  });
```

Earlier I was not passing maxAge. If I was not passing maxAge then cookie's maxAge was session then I changed it to maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30. It still did not work.

**Second**

I thought it was my cookie only which was deleted when killing/closing then while logging in user I tried to save auth token into localStorage so when user opens the PWA I would check if cookie is present, if present then ignore everything but if not then take auth token from localstorage and then again write it to cookie storage. It still did not work. This is working on local machine but not on server